# Firebase Storage signature does not match

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have read a lot of similar error, however, the solutions that I've found didn't work for me.
I have an issue when changing a profile picture, with the following error when loading the image into Google Chrome. 
The error is the following: `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method`.

The code that I'm using in the server is the following:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


const config = {
                action: 'read',
                expires: '03-01-2030'
            };

thumbFile.getSignedUrl(config)
```

This is my code via the server side for getting the signedUrl().
Why does my url gets invalidated after a week or so?

I've read the following answer which honestly I fear:
"The maximum duration of a Google Cloud Storage Signed URL is 7 days. But it can also be shorter. Never longer. I guess the Firebase Storage has the same limit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my previous answer is that the `admin.initializeApp();` must be initialized with the application's `serviceAccount`. That service account is constructed with the service account .json file gotten from the Firebase settings inside your project, like so:

```
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<YOUR APP ID>.appspot.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<YOUR APP ID>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Comment: I am also having the issue of SignatureDoesNotMatch on url after 7 days, does it solved the problem of invalidated getSignedUrl after a week?